# Where would I be able to get a square 1px font

Tags: fonts, terminal

So I've recently been distracted with image viewing in the terminal (I'm using PuTTY for unrelated reasons).

Not an ideal platform, but I was curious. After realizing that I could turn my font size down to get a more dense image, I eventually ended up with a regular font cranked all the way down to 1 px.
I also realized, that due to the nature of fonts, they're all taller than they are wide, and obviously have every character as a unique glyph.

Does anybody know where I would be able to obtain, or make, a font that is simply a square solid block for any non-whitespace character?

Is there a better solution for viewing images pixel-perfect in a terminal window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://strlen.com/square/

After changing my search a bit, I found this.
It at least fills the criteria for my font being square.